# etymology of looksie / look-see

Tags: etymology

Up until recently, I had believed there was a word "looksie" which meant "a quick/brief look", "a peek".

This seemed quite logical:
 - "a look" is a common noun.
 - "-sie" is a known diminutive suffix.

Thus, a look-sie would be a small look. On the contrary, results in dictionaries say the word is look-see, compounding the words "look" and "see". This construction does not make sense to me. Why would you combine "look" and "see"? You wouldn't have a "listen-hear".

Comment: FWIW, "let's look and see..." is a pretty common phrase, and "let's listen and hear [what someone has to say, for example]" is maybe less common but still not unusual at all. The first one might just seem more pleasing to the ear when shortened.

Comment: @ThePhoton ,well, not sure about that.  If it's shortened "let's look and see..." -> "let's looksee..." -.> "looksee at this." That's not right because the word under discussion is supposed to be a noun, not a verb

Comment: For some people, it's always been _look-see_; for others, it's like the way you had it analyzed. Still others never hear it in speech and therefore never have to make up a spelling for it. There isn't any Officially Correct Analysis, since everybody makes it up for themself.

Comment: Sounds like something that might well be like ‘long time no see’, a somewhat unnatural translation of a Chinese phrase that’s taken on a life of its own in English. Though in this case, the obvious Chinese equivalent to _looksie/look-see_ is 看见 (‘look see’) which just means ‘see (successfully)’; 看看 (‘look look’) would match the English phrase better, but a reduplicated form would be less likely to be translated with two different words…

Comment: "Look-see" has been idiomatic since I was a small child, and that was a long time ago.  It's obviously just a combo of "look" and "see".  It does imply a relatively brief look, but that was not the reason for "see".  The use of "-sie" to indicate a diminutive, while not new, did not gain popularity outside of bed apparel until perhaps the late 60s.

Comment: @HotLicks That doesn’t seem likely. _Itsy Bitsy Spider_ has been around much longer than that, and when _Itsy Bitsy Teeny Weeny Yellow Polkadot Bikini_ came out in 1960, the word was already well-established. Playing _footsie_ is known at least from the 1940s. And of course people have been called Betsy, Josie, Maisie, Patsy and so on for much longer as well. It may have spread as a suffix since the ‘60s, but there were plenty of __-sie/-sy_ words around before that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**look-see** (n.) etymonline.com

> "inspection," 1865, "Pidgin-like formation" [OED], first used in
>   representations of English as spoken by Chinese, from look (v.) + see
>   (v.).

From the [OED](https://1867%20%20%20Chambers's%20Jrnl.%209%20Nov.%20717/1%20%20%20He%20would%20often..come%20to%20my%20berth,%20as%20he%20said,%20%E2%80%98to%20look%20see%20how%20master%20was%E2%80%99.) 1867

> transitive v. To inspect, examine, look at (something). Chiefly with
>   indirect question as object: to see, find out, ascertain (how, if,
>   etc.).

and as a colloq. noun:

> colloquial.
>
> 1. A (quick) inspection or examination; a survey; a reconnaissance.In early use in representations or imitations of Chinese Pidgin English.

As in:

> 2006   J. Dibbell Play Money xiii. 91   The only human intervention
>   required was a quick daily look-see at how the gold was growing.

Comment: Oh – so I guess my comment above wasn’t completely off after all, and it is really parallel to ‘long time no see’. How quaint!

Comment: It's worth addng that "resultative complement" constructions like look-see (看见), and listen-hear (听到) are very common in Chinese.

Comment: "resultative complement" - very interesting!

Comment: @Sam That’s what they’re usually called in Chinese grammar. It’s a construction that doesn’t really exist in English. The odd thing about this one is that the English translation _doesn’t match_ the Chinese resultative complement construction. 看见 ‘look see’ doesn’t mean the same thing as English _look-see_ at all – it means ‘look, and as a result successfully see’ (i.e., it pretty much just means ‘see’).